# Pass variable to dataTask async function

Tags: ios, swift

I'm sending HTTP request asyncroniously and I want somehow to pass local variable into completion handler of that task. The problem is the variable is changing right after executing dataTask so I need to copy that variable.

```
var neededVariable = 1
for _ in 0...10 {
    let urlS = "https://sub2pewdiepie.com/subscribe.php?param1=123"
    let url = URL(string: urlS.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: 
CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: 
    { data, response, error in
        guard error = nil else {return}
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            print(neededVariable) 
            // code goes here...
        } catch let error { print(error.localizedDescription) }
    })
    task.resume()
    neededVariable += 1
    // code goes here...

}
```

That will print increased(for N times) values of course. How can I fix my var during initializing task?

Comment: `let temp = neededVariable` just before calling `dataTask` and then use `temp` instead?

Comment: So why don't you let `neededVariable` inside the `do` block instead?

Comment: I'm sorry guys, that all code should be in the loop. Then, Joakim, that wont work right? I've corrected question

Comment: Ahmad F, because I'm working with that variable outside of the task

Comment: Please learn to understand how asynchronous data processing works. The *variable is changing **before** executing dataTask*. What is the purpose of sending a couple of 100000 HTTP requests per second to a server?

Comment: Well, that is just an example, I wanted to show it's in the loop) Corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose `DispatchGroup` is the recommended API for example

```
var neededVariable = 1
let group = DispatchGroup()
let session = URLSession.shared
for _ in 0...10 {
    group.enter()
    let urlS = "https://sub2pewdiepie.com/subscribe.php?param1=123"
    let url = URL(string: urlS.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)!

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        defer(group.leave())
        if let error = error { print(error); return }
        do {
            neededVariable += 1
            print(neededVariable) 
        } catch let error { print(error.localizedDescription) }
    })
    task.resume()       

}

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
   print("notify", neededVariable)
}
```

Comment: This is good. I just initially for some reason was sure there is a way to pass some data into the task, seems there is not. Thanks

Comment: You can pass data top down, for example `group` is captured and available in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some tools for threads management. For example: semaphores.

First at all declare your semaphore before your data task starts:

`let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)`

then refactor a dataTask code:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler:
{ [weak self] data, response, error in // don't forget to use weak self to avoid memory leaks
    guard let `self` = self else { return }
    self.semaphore.wait()
    guard error = nil else {
        self.semaphore.signal()
        return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
        self.semaphore.signal()
        return
    }
    // you should not use do block here
    //do { 
    print(self.neededVariable)
    //} catch let error { print(error.localizedDescription) }

    self.semaphore.signal()
})
```

and of course:

```
task.resume()
semaphore.wait()
neededVariable = 2
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: It seems to me a it is a good idea to use a semaphore here, however do you think that is it necessary to implement `self.semaphore.wait()` inside the completion handler?

Comment: @AhmadF semaphore instance in this case is a class variable. So to avoid memory leaks inside a closure we have to write [weak self]. And because of [weak self] we should use self. to access to semaphore instance